# Error with Creating WAX account. "assertion failure with message: comparison of assets with different symbols is not allowed"

Tags: account-creation

I am uisng C# and eos-sharp to build a Wallet App for WAX Blockchain

When I Call Create Account Action on WAX Test New I receive this Exception :

code : 3050003

file: wasm_interface.cpp

line_number: 1131

message: assertion failure with message: comparison of assets with different symbols is not allowed

This is my code:

```
            var api = "https://testnet.wax.pink.gg";
            var chainId = "f16b1833c747c43682f4386fca9cbb327929334a762755ebec17f6f23c9b8a12";
            var privateKey = "XXX";
            var owner = "XXX";
            var permission = "private";
            var newAcc = "waxproto1112";
            var newAccOwnerPk = "EOS8YtPmxTYQJhUPEP59Y9GmuV2eicXiykYfy4rJjEcjZShtfXVqg";
            var newAccActivePk = "EOS64adYmQ6xGWJSW71ZgWS2Ez1cDWM2KVyRdrqKAddF8yHEtf7EY";
            var newAccRam = 2996;
            var newAccNet = "0.0100 WAX";
            var newAccCpu = "0.0100 WAX";

            var config = new EosConfigurator()
            {
                HttpEndpoint = api,
                ChainId = chainId,
                ExpireSeconds = 30,
                SignProvider = new DefaultSignProvider(privateKey)
            };
            var eos = new Eos(config);

            //Act
            var res = "";
            try
            {
                 res = eos.CreateTransaction(new Transaction()
                {
                    actions = new List<EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action>()
                {
                    new EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action()
                    {
                        account = "eosio",
                        authorization = new List<PermissionLevel>()
                        {
                            new PermissionLevel() {actor = owner, permission = permission}
                        },
                        name = "newaccount",
                        data = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                            { "creator",owner },
                            { "name", newAcc },
                            { "owner", new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                                { "threshold", 1 },
                                { "keys", new List<object>() {
                                    new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                                        { "key", newAccOwnerPk },
                                        { "weight", 1}
                                    }
                                }},
                                { "accounts", new List<object>() },
                                { "waits", new List<object>() }
                            }},
                            { "active", new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                                { "threshold", 1 },
                                { "keys", new List<object>() {
                                    new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                                        { "key", newAccActivePk },
                                        { "weight", 1}
                                    }
                                }},
                                { "accounts",  new List<object>() },
                                { "waits", new List<object>() }
                            }}
                        }
                    },
                    new EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action()
                    {
                        account = "eosio",
                        authorization = new List<PermissionLevel>()
                        {
                            new PermissionLevel() { actor = owner, permission = permission}
                        },
                        name = "buyrambytes",
                        data = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                            { "payer", owner },
                            { "receiver", newAcc },
                            { "bytes", newAccRam },
                        }
                    },
                    new EosSharp.Core.Api.v1.Action()
                    {
                        account = "eosio",
                        authorization = new List<PermissionLevel>()
                        {
                            new PermissionLevel() { actor = owner, permission = permission}
                        },
                        name = "delegatebw",
                        data = new Dictionary<string, object>() {
                            { "from", owner },
                            { "receiver", newAcc },
                            { "stake_net_quantity", newAccNet },
                            { "stake_cpu_quantity", newAccCpu },
                            { "transfer", false },
                        }
                    }
                }
                }).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            }
            catch (ApiErrorException ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Does anybody know why this error is happening although the blockchain symbol is matched with Net Stack and CPU Stack ??

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use 8 decimal places for the net and cpu